# Establecer la ventana activa en un QmdiArea

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Tengo un **`mdiArea`** al que le añado varias ventanas (de la clase **`QWidget`**):

```
self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.win_ts)
self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.win_vt)
self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.win_norm)
```

Por defecto, la última ventana añadida es la activa (`win_norm`), pero quiero que sea la primera (`win_ts`), para ello he visto el método [**`setActiveSubWindow`**](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmdiarea.html#setActiveSubWindow) pero recibe como parámetro un `QMdiSubWindow` y al hacer:

`self.mdiArea.setActiveSubWindow(self.win_ts)`

arroja error, obviamente.

He inentado crear QmdiSubWindows a partir de los QWidgets, pero parece no funcionar tampoco:

```
    window_ts = QMdiSubWindow()
    window_ts.setWidget(self.win_ts)
    window_vt = QMdiSubWindow(self.win_vt)
    window_vt.setWidget(self.win_vt)
    window_norm = QMdiSubWindow()
    window_norm.setWidget(self.win_norm)

    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(window_ts)
    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(window_vt)
    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(window_norm)

    self.mdiArea.setActiveSubWindow(window_ts)
```

¿Cómo puedo entonces establecer la ventana activa?

Soy relativamente nuevo en PyQt, así que cualquier sugerencia es de ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas al final es la forma correcta de hacerlo. Lo único raro que veo es `window_vt = QMdiSubWindow(self.win_vt)` que debería ser `window_vt = QMdiSubWindow()`. Si no, la causa de que no te funcione puede ser por conflicto de nombres. Ten en cuenta que tal y como está     `window_ts`, `window_vt` y `window_norm` son variables locales al método donde los defines. Si usas `self.mdiArea.setActiveSubWindow(window_ts)` fuera de dicho método no funcionará lógicamente. Por otro lado, usar el mismo nombre para las instancias de tus widgets y para las de `QMdiSubWindow` puede ser confuso e incluso inducir a errores. Habría que ver tu app completa o al menos el error que te lanza (si es que lo hace).

Dicho esto voy a explicar un poco como se debe hacer y a dar un ejemplo reproducible para mostrar su uso.

Debes crear `QMdiSubWindows` dentro del `QMdiarea`, luego añades los widgets que quieras a cada subventana como si se tratara de cualquier otra ventana (como hariamos en una `QMainWidget` por ejemplo).

El método `setActiveSubWindow` debe recibir una instancia de `QMdiSubWindows` en todo caso.

En el siguiente ejemplo se crean tres ventanas y colocamos el foco en la segunda que se crea. Cada ventana tiene un `QTextEdit` dentro, esto es solo como ejemplo y para que no sean ventanas vacías. Seria lo mismo para cualquier otro frame.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMdiSubWindow, QMdiArea, QTextEdit

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("MDI demo")
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)

        self.win_ts = QMdiSubWindow()
        self.win_ts.setWindowTitle("Window TS")
        self.win_ts.setWidget(QTextEdit())


        self.win_vt = QMdiSubWindow()
        self.win_vt.setWindowTitle("Window VT")
        self.win_vt.setWidget(QTextEdit())

        self.win_norm = sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        self.win_norm.setWindowTitle("Window Norm")
        self.win_norm.setWidget(QTextEdit())

        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.win_ts)
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.win_vt)
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.win_norm)

        self.win_ts.show()
        self.win_vt.show()
        self.win_norm.show()

        self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows() # Ordena las ventanas en cascada

        self.mdi.setActiveSubWindow(self.win_vt) #<<<<<<<<


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Lo que nos debe producir algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos ver como el foco aparece en la segunda ventana (`self.win_vt`) tal y como queriamos.